# PHP : Error in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello i have a question about some SQL query that keep give me an error
Code :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid' and set emailchange=1");
```

the query keep giving me an error
any help ?

Comment: `and set emailchange=1` ?!? WTF! Do you actually have a column name called `set emailexchange` with a space in it?

Comment: @MarkBaker no emailchange is other column that i want to change to 1

Comment: @Dagon no error just the query don't work at all

Comment: you cant create a select like that you could do an update with a sub-querry select however. No error, because you you don't properly check for one

Comment: You're trying to UPDATE and to SELECT in a single statement? If you need to do the select as well, then do this as two separate statements...

Comment: so there is no way to make this query work ? @Dagon

Comment: yes , can i do this ? @MarkBaker

Comment: `$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid'")`  and `$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE email set emailchange=1 WHERE user_id='$uid'");`

Comment: Clearly you're a beginner..... drop whatever tutorial you're using, stop using the MySQL extension, and find a tutorial that uses MySQLi or PDO and that teaches about prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: can i use the ";" or something to separate query's? @MarkBaker

Comment: @MarkBaker can it be `$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid';UPDATE email set emailchange=1 WHERE user_id='$uid'");  
`?

Comment: @user3813111 - No!!! Do what I've said, learn to use MySQLi or PDO, and use bind variables, and use two statements. In addition to being insecure, the MySQL extension is officially deprecated in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id=$uid and emailchange=1");
```

Comment: no, i want to update emailchange and in the same time select email

Answer (score 0):

You can also update after select the data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid' and set emailchange=1");  
if($result){
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE email set emailchange=1 WHERE user_id='$uid'");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the set here:

```
and set emailchange=1
```

You can't select and update in the same SQL statement, you need to execute the update statement then write a select statement to grab the email - assuming that is what you mean to do so:

Update the field:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users set emailchange = 1 where user_id='$uid'");
```

select the data:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("select email from users where user_id='$uid'");
```

You really should escape $uid before passing it to the query and ideally you should be using PDO!